# 2D JRadioButton object array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am creating a survey form using java swing. I'm loading questions and answers from my database to the view and I'm dynamically loading radio buttons (answers) to the view.

I created a 2D array to generate JRadioButton objects.

```
JRadioButton[][] rdbtnanswer;

public method() {
    int ans_yval = 0; 

    for (int i = 0; i < questions.getNumberOfQuestions(); i++) {

        String questionnair = questions.getQuestion(i);

        Vector<Answers> vector_answers = questions.getAnswer(questionnair);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

         rdbtnanswer = new JRadioButton[questions.getNumberOfQuestions()][vector_answers.size()];

         for (int v = 0; v < vector_answers.size(); v++) {

            rdbtnanswer[i][v] = new JRadioButton(vector_answers.get(v).getAnswers());
            rdbtnanswer[i][v].setBounds(31, 170+ans_yval, 236, 23);
            contentPane.add(rdbtnanswer[i][v]); 
            group.add(rdbtnanswer[i][v]);

             ans_yval = ans_yval + 25; 
         }          
    }
}
```

I get the answers in the UI perfectly.

But when I create another inner, outer for loop and try to print the `rdbtnanswer` object values, values are not there. Each array replaced from last one. I need the reason for that.

Comment: The code is not clear to me: 1. `rdbtnanswe[][]` is not defined anywhere. 2. `answerName` is not defined 3.Set bounds depends only on `y` value so why have a 2d array ?  Recommendations: 1. Do not set bounds. Instead use a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) 2. post [mre]

Comment: @c0der I edited the code now. I got the view perfectly. The thing is when i print the rdbtnanswer 2D array values again all values are replaces from last values

Comment: Anyone? I need help

Comment: Before asking for more help please use the help you already got. Your last edit cleared only 1. and 2. from my previous comment and ignored the recommendations. One thing is clear from what you posted: you construct `rdbtnanswer = new JRadioButton[][]`  with every (external) loop, so you can't expect it to have previously set values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem (or the solution in this case) could be like so:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

class Main {

    private JRadioButton[][] rdbtnanswer;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main().method();
    }

    public void method() {

        int numberOfQuestions = 5; //questions.getNumberOfQuestions();
        rdbtnanswer = new JRadioButton[numberOfQuestions ][0];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
            Vector<String> vector_answers = getAnswer(i);
            JRadioButton[] rowOfButtons = new JRadioButton[vector_answers.size()];
             for (int v = 0; v < vector_answers.size(); v++) {
                 rowOfButtons[v] = new JRadioButton(vector_answers.get(v));
             }
             rdbtnanswer[i]= rowOfButtons;
        }

        //printout for testing 
        for(JRadioButton[] rowOfButtons : rdbtnanswer) {
            for(JRadioButton btn : rowOfButtons) {
                System.out.print(btn.getText()); //print row 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //create a vector of Strings with values "0", "1", ......."i" for testing
    private Vector<String> getAnswer(int i) {
        List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, i+1).boxed().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new Vector<>(list);
    }
}
```